# Inter-Controller roaming between Juniper and Cisco AP

Tags: wifi, controller, wireless-bridge

Corporate network is mainly composed of Cisco WLC and Lightweight APs.

They are all using Wireless G and N.

The office is asking to deploy Juniper WLC and APs to a new space in the office.

I'm going to implement inter-controller roaming between the two vendor APs.

They will have same SSID, different channel and controllers associated.

Is this going to be a simple roaming or would it cause hosts to recognize a different vendor's SSID as a duplicate?

As in if the SSID is "raining" would the different vendor's AP make the hosts recognize it as same "raining" or "raining (2)?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as:

(1) SSID are the same.

(2) APs are in different subnet via WLC.

(3) Same authentication type. (EAP, 8021X, etc)

(4) Different channel

(5) Same 2.5GhZ.

Inter-controller roaming will take place.